# Kendo UI Treeview and XML

Tags: xml, kendo-ui

In Kendo UI i try to bind simple xml data to treeview widjet, with following code:

```
<script>

    $(document).ready(function () {
        var ds = new kendo.data.HierarchicalDataSource({
            transport: {
                read: {
                    url: "kendoTWData.xml", dataType: "xml"
                }
            },
            schema   : {type: "xml",
                data        : '/root/doc',
                model       : {
                    fields: {
                        nome: "nome/text()"
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        $("#treeview").kendoTreeView({
            dataSource   : ds,
            dataTextField: "nome"
        });
    });
</script>
```

The xml file looks very simple (just for test purpose):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<root>
<doc><nome>fabio</nome></doc>
<doc><nome>mauro</nome></doc>
</root>
```

But nothing appear... only "Loading... " message.

The web console of firefox report:

[11:57:03.558] TypeError: item.level is not a function @ kendo.web.min.js:11

Can someone please point me to the right direction?

Thanks in advance

Comment: have you downloaded all prerequisites (jquery of the required version, other kendo-libs when using a custom-built distribution) ? have you renamed any of the lib files ? does the error also occur when using non-minified libs ? does the error occur using other  browsers ? other ff versions ?

Comment: Thank-you for reply.

I use the jquery version 'in bundle' with the kendo package and samples (kendoui.web.2013.1.319.open-source).

Same result with other version of jquery.

Same error with IE, FF adn Chrome... even with non-minified libs (kendo.web.js).

:-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try defining the model as:

```
model: {
    fields: {
        nome : "nome/text()"
    },
    level: function() { return 0; }
}
```

This should make the *trick*.

Comment: I cannot get how are you defining the `children` since both `fabio` and `mauro` are at the same level.

Comment: Thank-you OnaBai... it works!!

Now... how can I modify the code for hierarchical pourpose??

For example if i modify the xml file for childs elements, in this way:

     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
       <root>
        <doc>
           <nome>fabio</nome>
              <subdocs>
                  <doc>
                     <nome>OnaBai</nome>
                  </doc>
              </subdocs>   
         </doc>
          <doc>
             <nome>mauro</nome>
          </doc>
       </root>

Comment: I'm not sure if XML DataSources are actually supported -even that we made it run for the initial case-. I've asked it in KendoUI official forums and if the respond I'll let you know. Do you really need it to be XML? :-(

Comment: (XML is no strictly required, but I have many classes in my project that provides data in this format)